# Leetcode 102: Binary tree level-order traversal in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, tree, swift

> ### [102. Binary Tree Level Order Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/)
>
> Given a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).
>
> **For example:**
>
> Given binary tree [3,9,20,null,null,15,7],
>
> ```
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> ```
>
> return its level order traversal as:
>
> ```
> [
>   [3],
>   [9,20],
>   [15,7]
> ]
> ```

This is my solution in Swift:

```
func levelOrder(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [[Int]] {
        guard let root = root else{
            return []
        }
        let nodes = recursiveVisit(root)
        let capacity = nodes.reduce([Int]()) {
            if $0.contains($1.0) == false {
                return $0 + [$1.0]
            }
            return $0
        }.count
        return nodes.reduce([[Int]](repeating: [], count: capacity), { 
          var tmp = $0
            tmp[$1.0].append($1.1)
            return tmp
        })
    }


func recursiveVisit(_ node: TreeNode?) -> [(Int, Int)]{
        //  [(Int,  Int)]
        //  depth,      node.val

        guard let node = node else{
            return []
        }

        var nodes = [(Int, Int)]()
        nodes.append((0, node.val))

        let lhs = recursiveVisit(node.left).map {
            return ($0.0 + 1, $0.1)
        }

        let rhs = recursiveVisit(node.right).map {
            return ($0.0 + 1, $0.1)
        }
        nodes.append(contentsOf: lhs)
        nodes.append(contentsOf: rhs)
        return nodes
    }
```

The solution is very intuitive: collect the nodes' value and depth, then reduce to the answer.

It is not as well designed as [the Java Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/discuss/33450/Java-solution-with-a-queue-used), though.

My question is mainly on the Swift syntax.  Is there any other way to do it more lean? Combine the two `reduce()` calls to one, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simplifying your code

Let's start here:

> ```
> let capacity = nodes.reduce([Int]()) {
>     if $0.contains($1.0) == false {
>         return $0 + [$1.0]
>     }
>     return $0
> }.count
> ```

The test

```
if $0.contains($1.0) == false
```

is shorter (and – in my opinion – better) written as

```
if !$0.contains($1.0)
```

Each invocation of the closure creates a new array. In such cases it is more efficient to use `reduce(into:)` with a closure that *updates* the array:

```
let capacity = nodes.reduce(into: [Int]()) {
    if !$0.contains($1.0) {
        $0.append($1.0)
    }
}.count
```

But what this code actually does is to determine the number of distinct levels in the `nodes` array. That is simpler and more efficiently done with a *set:*

```
let capacity = Set(nodes.map { $0.0 }).count
```

Here

> ```
> return nodes.reduce([[Int]](repeating: [], count: capacity), {
>     var tmp = $0
>     tmp[$1.0].append($1.1)
>     return tmp
> })
> ```

a new nested array is created with each invocation of the closure. Again, this can be improved with `reduce(into:)`, so that the first function becomes

```
func levelOrder(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [[Int]] {
    guard let root = root else {
        return []
    }
    let nodes = recursiveVisit(root)
    let capacity = Set(nodes.map { $0.0 }).count
    return nodes.reduce(into: [[Int]](repeating: [], count: capacity), {
        $0[$1.0].append($1.1)
    })
}
```

I have only minor suggestions for the second function:

> ```
> var nodes = [(Int, Int)]()
> nodes.append((0, node.val))
> ```

can be combined to

```
var nodes = [(0, node.val)]
```

The results of the recursive calls can be appended to the `nodes` array directly:

```
nodes += recursiveVisit(node.left).map {
    return ($0.0 + 1, $0.1)
}
nodes += recursiveVisit(node.right).map {
    return ($0.0 + 1, $0.1)
}
```

And if you use tuple *labels* then the code becomes better readable (and almost self-documenting):

```
func recursiveVisit(_ node: TreeNode?) -> [(level: Int, value: Int)] {

    guard let node = node else {
        return []
    }
    var nodes = [(level: 0, value: node.val)]
    nodes += recursiveVisit(node.left).map {
        return (level: $0.level + 1, value: $0.value)
    }
    nodes += recursiveVisit(node.right).map {
        return (level: $0.level + 1, value: $0.value)
    }
    return nodes
}
```

This can be used in the first function as well. As an alternative, define a custom `struct` with “level” and “label” members.

#### Alternative #1 – A nested function

It is not necessary to create an array of `(level, value)` tuples first. You can add a value to the sublist on the current level, or append a new level while traversing the tree recursively. With a *nested function* you don't even have to pass the array around:

```
func levelOrder(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [[Int]] {
    var levels: [[Int]] = []

    func recursiveVisit(_ node: TreeNode?, level: Int) {
        guard let node = node else {
            return
        }
        if level < levels.count {
            levels[level].append(node.val)
        } else {
            levels.append([node.val])
        }
        recursiveVisit(node.left, level: level + 1)
        recursiveVisit(node.right, level: level + 1)
    }

    recursiveVisit(root, level: 0)
    return levels
}
```

#### Alternative #2 – Iteration instead of recursion

The referenced Java solution solves the task with iteration, and a list containing all nodes on the current level. Of course that can be done in Swift as well. Here is an example of a quite compact implementation:

```
func levelOrder(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [[Int]] {
    guard let root = root else {
        return []
    }

    var wrapList: [[Int]] = []
    var queue = [root] // First level

    while !queue.isEmpty {
        // All values of nodes on the current level:
        wrapList.append(queue.map { $0.val })
        // Replace queue by list of all nodes on the next level:
        queue = queue.flatMap { [$0.left, $0.right ] }.compactMap { $0 }
    }

    return wrapList
}
```

Comment: "And if you use tuple labels then the code becomes better readable (and almost self-documenting)" great plus to this - before it was just unreadable for me, with very labels very clear to understand. also the map should not use the short hand parameters to understand it better as a reader